# Debian Jessie without systemd and with initramfs hangs at boot

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, armbian

I need to use Jessie without `systemd` and with `initramfs`.

But there seems to be some incompatibilities. During boot, I get:

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... /scripts/init-premount/devpts: line 21: mountpoint: not found
```

It seems that the  `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/udev` uses `systemd` (which I uninstalled from my system and replaced with `sysvinit`):

```
#Content of udev
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon --resolve-names=never
#Content of udev (to be continued)
```

So it does not correctly mounts and prepare the system for the `devpts` and next scripts. Hence the errors at boot.

Would re-using `initramfs` (from init-top to init-bottom) scripts from previous Debian version (wheezy) work ?

Or is there another (and simpler way) to make my current initramfs work (modifying only some of the files) ?

**EDIT:**
I use a flavour of Debian named Armbian. I do not have any desktop environment and only use it as a headless server

Comment: I assume you remove --purge systemd, if so, did you manually force creating a new initrd.img? Also, the `/etc/udev/udev.conf` file might not set any logging output, in which case you might want to set it to `udev_log="err" ` to get any output during boot (which before that might look like it's hanging for up to a minute).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install `Sysvinit` package :

```
apt-get install sysvinit-core sysvinit-utils
cp /usr/share/sysvinit/inittab /etc/inittab
```

Configure grub:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` file and change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="init=/lib/sysvinit/init console=hvc0 console=ttyS0"
```

update `grub`:

```
update-grub
```

Reboot then  remove all of the systemd packages:

```
apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove systemd
```

To prevent `apt` from installing systemd packages in the future, run:

```
echo -e 'Package: systemd\nPin: release *\nPin-Priority: -1' > /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
echo -e '\n\nPackage: *systemd*\nPin: release *\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
```

Pin essential packages to wheezy:

```
echo deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy.list
echo -e '\n\nPackage: policykit-1\nPin: origin "wheezy"\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
echo -e '\n\nPackage: libpolkit-*\nPin: origin "wheezy"\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
echo -e '\n\nPackage: upower\nPin: origin "wheezy"\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
```

Install polkit:

```
apt-get install polkit-1 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 upower udisks
```

Reboot

[Source](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation)

Comment: First part is already done. Why using wheezy to pin essential packages ? Will it automatically configure initramfs to used theses packages ?